# serialize isn't working anymore like it should

Tags: jquery, serialization, input, checkbox

the serialize isn't working anymore like it should.it only selects those input's checked that are visible in DataTables oTable.

```
jQuery(':checkbox').live('click',function(){
    var nn = jQuery('input:checked', oTable).serialize();
    var n=nn.length;
    if (n!='0'){
        jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    else {
        jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',true);
        }
});    
    jQuery('#osszes').submit(function(){
        jQuery("input:hidden").remove();
        var fields = jQuery('input', oTable).serializeArray();
        jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
            jQuery('<input type="hidden" id="imSpProt" name="imSpProt[]" value="' + field.value + '" />').appendTo('#inputok');
            });
    });
```

Comment: which version of jquery you are using.

Comment: use on instead live beacause live is deprecated in latest versions

Comment: i have to go now to work but when i get home i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
jQuery(':checkbox').on('click',function(){
var nn = jQuery('input:checked', oTable).serialize();
var n=nn.length;
if (n!='0'){
    jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',false);
    }
else {
    jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',true);
    }
});    

jQuery('#osszes').submit(function(){
    jQuery("input:hidden").remove();
    var fields = jQuery('input', oTable).serializeArray();
    jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
        jQuery('<input type="hidden" id="imSpProt" name="imSpProt[]" value="' + field.value + '" />').appendTo('#inputok');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the length of the string returned by `.serialize()`, there is no need to use `.seialize()`.

If you just want to check if there is a checked check box, you just need to do:

```
$('#imObjectForm').prop('disabled', $('input:checked', oTable).length == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working again.Thanks 4 your quick reply on this. well the biggest problem here was a missing

> o

at : `oTable = jQuery('#table_id').dataTable({`

```
jQuery(':checkbox').on('click',function(){
    var nn = jQuery('input:checked', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
    var n=nn.length;
    if (n!='0'){
        jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',false);
        }
    else {
        jQuery('#imObjectForm').attr('disabled',true);
        }
});    
    jQuery('#osszes').submit(function(){
        jQuery("input:hidden").remove();
        var fields = jQuery('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serializeArray();
        jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
            jQuery('<input type="hidden" id="imSpProt" name="imSpProt[]" value="' + field.value + '" />').appendTo('#inputok');
            });
    });
oTable = jQuery('#table_id').dataTable({
```